# SQL loop does nothing but if execute it manually. its working

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, procedure

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS updatePrice // 
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `updatePrice`()

BEGIN

DECLARE rowCount INT(50);
DECLARE currentRow INT(50);
DECLARE containerTyp VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE regularPrice VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE postID INT(50);

SET rowCount=(SELECT COUNT(update_price.ID) FROM update_price);
SET currentRow = 1;

updateLoop: WHILE (currentRow < rowCount) DO

    SET containerTyp = (SELECT update_price.Typ from update_price WHERE update_price.ID = currentRow);
    SET regularPrice = (SELECT update_price.regularPrice from update_price WHERE update_price.ID = currentRow);
    SET postID = (SELECT wp.post_id FROM wp_postmeta wp WHERE wp.meta_key = '_sku' AND wp.meta_value = containerTyp);   
    UPDATE wp_postmeta SET wp_postmeta.meta_value = regularPrice WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' AND wp_postmeta.post_id = postID;
            
    SET currentRow = currentRow + 1;
    
END WHILE updateLoop;

END//


DELIMITER ;
```

Thats my code. The problem is when i execute it. It does nohting. But if i manually do the select and the Update it finds data and changes it. I dont know if i have to do some settings. I use HeidiSQL client or phpmyadmin. Mysql in MariaDb.

Comment: are you executing this sql script or directly the procedure you've created.

Comment: Add some debugging to your procedure.  Add statements to record what value is assigned to `rowCount`, for example.  *(If the value assigned is `1` then you've got `WHILE (1 < 1) DO` which is never really going to do very much.)*  Then do the same for the other SET statements.  *(Though, you're probably better off using a cursor to iterate through the ID's.  Your current loop ONLY works if the value are sequential and have no gaps, which is highly unlikely to be the case forever.)*

Comment: ty yildizyasin. I execute my procedure in a seperat Query. call updatePrice();
yes i thougt about that but my database has no gabs every containerTyp is unqiue in my Table. Everycontainertype has a _sku.

Comment: @MatBailie yes u are right. If i test it on 1 it crashed. So something in the loop is not right. Can u maybe see my mistake ?